# jqGrid filterToolbar not working - ASP.NET

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to implement the ToolBar Search/Filtering for jqGrid.   When I enter some text in any of the filters and hit enter nothing happens - not sure what I have done wrong here.  Any help is appreciated:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'json',
            url: 'GetIncidents.ashx?view=MyIncidents',
            height: "100%",
            scrollOffset: 0,
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                cell: "cell",
                id: "ID",
                userdata: "userdata",
                subgrid: {
                    root: "rows",
                    repeatitems: true,
                    cell: "cell"
                }
            },
            colNames: ['ID', 'Title', 'Assigned To', 'Status', 'Priority', 'Classification', 'Affected User', 'Support Group', 'Last Modified'],
            colModel: [
                  { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 40, sorttype: 'int', firstsortorder: 'desc' },
                  { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 180 },
                  { name: 'AssignedUser', index: 'AssignedUser', width: 100, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 50, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'Priority', index: 'Priority', width: 50, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'Classification', index: 'Classification', width: 150, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'AffectedUser', index: 'AffectedUser', width: 100, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'TierQueue', index: 'TierQueue', width: 100, align: 'center' },
                  { name: 'LastModified', index: 'LastModified', width: 120, align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s0', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i A'}}],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 15,
            width: 980,                
            sortname: 'ID',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            autowidth: true,
            gridview: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: 'All Open Incidents Assigned To Me',
            onSelectRow: function (id) { window.location = 'ViewIncident.aspx?id=' + id; }
        });

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid relies on the server for the filtering functionality, if you examine your outgoing post action you will see the extra data it is adding to the post passing the filtering data.

So your filtering will be done on the server, your then filtered dataset will be ordered/paged, etc and then passed back to your jqGrid.

In my mind this is the place to start:
[ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Implementation of searching in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid)

From that example it will take a bit of effort to set up but from there you will have a nice base to handle dynamic filtering. If you are only dealing with very basic filtering you can probably use some of the components to hack out something but much past a basic requirement will make it worth investing the time into this extra option.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things first try to add the document.ready function let your browser load before firing up the grid and then add loadonce: true,

then try to run it and it should work!

Here is the code

```
 JQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        url: 'GetIncidents.ashx?view=MyIncidents',
        height: "100%",
        scrollOffset: 0,
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "ID",
            userdata: "userdata",
            subgrid: {
                root: "rows",
                repeatitems: true,
                cell: "cell"
            }
        },
        colNames: ['ID', 'Title', 'Assigned To', 'Status', 'Priority', 'Classification', 'Affected User', 'Support Group', 'Last Modified'],
        colModel: [
              { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 40, sorttype: 'int', firstsortorder: 'desc' },
              { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 180 },
              { name: 'AssignedUser', index: 'AssignedUser', width: 100, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 50, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'Priority', index: 'Priority', width: 50, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'Classification', index: 'Classification', width: 150, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'AffectedUser', index: 'AffectedUser', width: 100, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'TierQueue', index: 'TierQueue', width: 100, align: 'center' },
              { name: 'LastModified', index: 'LastModified', width: 120, align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s0', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i A'}}],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 15,
        width: 980,                
        sortname: 'ID',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth: true,
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadonce:true,  //**you need to add this**
        caption: 'All Open Incidents Assigned To Me',
        onSelectRow: function (id) { window.location = 'ViewIncident.aspx?id=' + id; }
    });

    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

})